# Group RDD entries by timestamps into the lists of entries covering X minutes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have the following entries in RDD:

```
(111,List(List(1473163148,abc)))
(111,List(List(1473163143,def)))
(111,List(List(1473163143,abd)))
(111,List(List(1473163139,asd)))
(111,List(List(1473163696,rtf)))
(111,List(List(1473163700,rgd)))
(111,List(List(1473163703,dmf)))
```

I want to group these entries into new entries, so that each new entry would contain a list of old entries within 30 minutes. It seems to be straightforward but in the practice my code does not do the trick.

```
val grouped = processed.reduceByKey((x,y) => x ++ y)
val separated = grouped.flatMap { case (k, l) => MyFuncObj.createGroups(l).map(sublist => (k, sublist)) }

object MyFuncObj {

  def createGroups(l: List[List[Any]]): Iterable[List[List[Any]]] = {
    l.groupBy(_.productElement(0).toString.toLong / 30*60).values
  }

}
```

After applying this code to the above data, I get the following result (I only provide the timestamps because this is the key point):

```
1473163143  1473163143  1473163148      
1473163139              
1473163696  1473163700  1473163703      
1473168932
```

Since these timestamps are seconds, they should be grouped as follows:

```
1473163143  1473163143  1473163148  1473163139  1473163696  1473163700  1473163703
1473168932
```

How to solve this task?

**UPDATE:**

To be more clear: I expect to get 30-minute buckets starting at the time of the first record.

Comment: question is still unclear: expected output contains timestamp `1473168932` which doesn't appear in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. If you want the "buckets" to start at the time of the first entry - you should use the **delta** between each timestamp and that first timestamp before you make the division
2. Missing parenthesis around `30*60` - you're dividing by 30 and *then* multiplying that result by 60, instead of dividing by `(30*60)`:

   ```
   scala> 5000 / 30*60
   res0: Int = 9960

   scala> 5000 / (30*60)
   res1: Int = 2
   ```

Altogether - this seems to do what you need:

```
// sample data:
val processed = sc.parallelize(List(
  (111,List(List(1473163148L, "abc"))),
  (111,List(List(1473163143L,"def"))),
  (111,List(List(1473163143L,"abd"))),
  (111,List(List(1473163139L,"asd"))),
  (111,List(List(1473163696L,"rtf"))),
  (111,List(List(1473163700L,"rgd"))),
  (111,List(List(1473168932L,"dmf"))))
)


// first - find the lowest timsestamp:
// if input isn't ordered:
val firstTimestamp: Long = processed.values.map { case List((l: Long) :: _) => l }.min()

// if input is sorted by timestamp:
val firstTimestamp: Long = processed.first()._2.head.head.toString.toLong

def createGroups(l: List[List[Any]]): Iterable[List[List[Any]]] = {
  // divide the DELTA between each timestamp and first one by 30 minutes to find bucket:
  l.groupBy(t => (firstTimestamp - t.productElement(0).toString.toLong) / (30*60)).values
}

// continue as you did:
val grouped: RDD[(Int, List[List[Any]])] = processed.reduceByKey((x, y) => x ++ y)
val separated: RDD[(Int, List[List[Any]])] = grouped.flatMap {
  case (k, l) => createGroups(l).map(sublist => (k, sublist))
}

separated.foreach(println)
// prints:
// (111,List(List(1473168932, dmf)))
// (111,List(List(1473163148, abc), List(1473163143, def), List(1473163143, abd), List(1473163139, asd), List(1473163696, rtf), List(1473163700, rgd)))
```

Comment: Thanks. The only issue is at the line `val firstTimestamp: Long = processed.values.map { case List((l: Long) :: _) => l }.min()`. I get the error `Scruntinee is incompatible with pattern type, found: Long, required: String`.

Comment: I assumed the timestamps are of type `Long` in the input data (your question didn't define the types) - if they are Strings, change the type in that line to String and call `l.toLong`.

Comment: `val firstTimestamp: Long = processed.values.map { case List((l: String) :: _) => l.toLong }.min()`. This gives me the error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection`

Comment: Dude, my answer works on the sample data you provided, there's nothing else I can do - I can't _guess_ other irregularities you might have in your data that I can't see. You'll have to figure out that part on your own, or narrow the issue down and ask a separate question.